# How to make Windows XP installation choose another drive to store its installation files?

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I've Windows XP installation ISO along with the key and I don't have optical drive on this computer. So, I've mounted ISO and started the setup.

Currently, Windows XP is installed in C: drive and I want to format the same and reinstall again in the same C: drive.

I've used advanced mode installation in setup and selected the option "Choose drive while install" option and also checked "Copy all installation files to hard drive".

It copied all installation files from ISO to D: drive but it stored around 15MB worth files in C: drive. Now, this is creating the problem. After reboot, while installing its not allowing me delete the C: partition. It says "files required for installation are stored on this drive. So, can't format".

How do I make the installation store all the required files on some other drive and format C: drive?

Comment: what is the amount of hard disk space and how you partitioned the drive ?

Comment: Its a 80GB hard disk. C: drive 12GB, rest is taken by D,E,F drives

Comment: You can only format C drive (already installed Xp) using cd/dvd only,

Comment: Now if you ready to format any other partition there is a another way i can tell, like booting from hard disk drive and installing to other partition . after that we format the old windows partition

Comment: My DVD drive also not works properly so i prefer always use unetbootin tool to install OS , If you have USB drive its more simple too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

Download [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and copy it to any other partition you have free space above 6 GB.
Now run unetbootin it will prompt you to mount ISO file ,mount it .Restart after completion.

The unetbootin will add entry in your boot loader menu ,choose unetbootin boot option from bootloader menu, now its works like DVD drive ,In XP setup menu try formating the previously installed partition . Hope it will work for you.

If not ,format any other remaining partition and install XP after that you can format old partition using many other free tools .